# Receiving inconsistent data in Go api

Tags: go, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I was learning the Go language and tested Google Cloud Functions with go + Google Firestore as the database.

While I was testing the response I got inconsistent responses.

I have used the json Marshaller to convert Firebase data to Json object to return from the API, this API is hosted in the Google Cloud Functions.

```
// Package p contains an HTTP Cloud Function.
package p

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    s "strings"

    "encoding/json"

    "cloud.google.com/go/firestore"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
)


func HelloWorld(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    path := s.Replace(r.URL.Path, "/", "", -1)

    ctx := context.Background()
    client := createClient(ctx)

    iter := client.Collection("profile").Where("publicUrl", "==", path).Documents(ctx)
    for {
        doc, err := iter.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        var publicDTO PublicDTO
        var Profile Profile
        doc.DataTo(&Profile)

        publicDTO.Profile = Profile

        b, err := json.Marshal(publicDTO)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.Write(b)
    }

}

func createClient(ctx context.Context) *firestore.Client {
    projectID := "projectId"

    client, err := firestore.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create client: %v", err)
    }
    return client
}

type PublicDTO struct {
    Profile       Profile     `json:"profile"`
}

type Profile struct {
    Id           string            `json:"id"`
    FirstName    string            `json:"firstName"`
    LastName     string            `json:"lastName"`
    FullName     string            `json:"fullName"`
    Email        string            `json:"email"`
    ImageUrl     string            `json:"imageUrl"`
    CoverPic     string            `json:"coverPic"`
    Experience   int               `json:"experience"`
    PhoneNumber  string            `json:"phoneNumber"`
    Description  string            `json:"description"`
    Address      string            `json:"address"`
    State        string            `json:"state"`
    Country      string            `json:"country"`
    Dob          map[string]string `json:"dob"`
    Website      string            `json:"website"`
    Reputation   int               `json:"reputation"`
    MemberFrom   map[string]int    `json:"memberFrom"`
    Title        string            `json:"title"`
    Organization string            `json:"organization"`
    Status       string            `json:"status"`
    Setup        int               `json:"setup"`
    Social       map[string]string `json:"social"`
    PublicUrl    string            `json:"publicUrl"`
    Language     []string          `json:"language"`
    Interests    []string          `json:"interests"`
}
```

but each time the response i'm getting is inconsistent, some of the values are missing.

Comment: Can you clarify what you where expecting to get in the link you sent, it seems to behave consistently. Can you try and explain the various services that are involved here and their interactions?

Comment: Always getting the same kind of json response. What are you expecting?

Comment: i was getting different different of json for same request, example 
in one request i'll get firstName and next request first name will be null. after making 3rd or 4 request i'll get all fields and then next request goes with few fields and values.

Comment: I am getting the same response always whenever I am clicking the API link you have provided. Can you provide the screenshots showing the different responses you are getting for the same request?

Comment: @Prabir i did some update to the api as i was trying around other way.

Comment: Does that mean you are getting the same response always or you are still getting different responses for the same request?

Comment: Exactly, same request getting different response, like sometimes missing the one field another time that will be shown, i think the non blocking of go might be the reason.

Comment: It seems the following part of the function code has some issues.
 
  `path := s.Replace(r.URL.Path, "/", "", -1)
 ctx := context.Background()
 client := createClient(ctx)
 iter := client.Collection("profile").Where("publicUrl", "==", path).Documents(ctx)`
 
I would suggest you check the content of the collection and add logging in the function where you are expecting the data from the collection and see if the logging is giving consistent results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution i got after marshal and unmarshal, it works as expected.

```
package p

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    s "strings"
    "time"

    "cloud.google.com/go/firestore"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
)

var ctx context.Context
var client *firestore.Client

func PublicApi(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    path := s.Replace(r.URL.Path, "/", "", -1)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")

    newFsConfigBytes, _ := json.Marshal(getPublicDTO(path))
    w.Write(newFsConfigBytes)
}

func getPublicDTO(path string) (publicDTO publicDTO) {
    ctx = context.Background()
    client = createClient()
    profile, id := getProfiles(path)
    publicDTO.Profile = profile
    publicDTO.MilestoneDTOS = getMilestone(id)
    return
}

func getProfiles(link string) (profile, string) {
    var retVal profile
    var id string
    iter := client.Collection("profile").Where("publicUrl", "==", link).Documents(ctx)
    for {
        doc, err := iter.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        id = doc.Ref.ID
        b, _ := json.Marshal(doc.Data())
        json.Unmarshal(b, &retVal)
    }
    return retVal, id
}

func getMilestone(id string) []milestoneDTOS {
    var retVal []milestoneDTOS
    iter := client.Collection("milestone").Where("userId", "==", id).Documents(ctx)

    for {
        var milestoneDTO milestoneDTOS
        doc, err := iter.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        b, _ := json.Marshal(doc.Data())
        err = json.Unmarshal(b, &milestoneDTO)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        retVal = append(retVal, milestoneDTO)
    }
    return retVal
}

func createClient() *firestore.Client {
    projectID := "app_id_asda"

    client, err := firestore.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create client: %v", err)
    }
    return client
}

type profile struct {
    Address          string    `json:"address"`
    City             string    `json:"city"`
    Country          string    `json:"country"`
    CoverPic         string    `json:"coverPic"`
    CreatedBy        string    `json:"createdBy"`
    CreatedDate      int       `json:"createdDate"`
    Description      string    `json:"description"`
    Dob              int64     `json:"dob"`
    Email            string    `json:"email"`
    Enabled          bool      `json:"enabled"`
    Experience       int       `json:"experience"`
    FirstName        string    `json:"firstName"`
    FullName         string    `json:"fullName"`
    FullNameNoSpace  string    `json:"fullNameNoSpace"`
    ImageURL         string    `json:"imageUrl"`
    Interests        []string  `json:"interests"`
    IsEnabled        bool      `json:"isEnabled"`
    Language         string    `json:"language"`
    LastModifiedDate int       `json:"lastModifiedDate"`
    LastName         string    `json:"lastName"`
    LatLng           string    `json:"latLng"`
    MemberFrom       time.Time `json:"memberFrom"`
    ObjectID         string    `json:"objectID"`
    Organization     string    `json:"organization"`
    PhoneNumber      string    `json:"phoneNumber"`
    PlanID           string    `json:"planId"`
    PublicURL        string    `json:"publicUrl"`
    Reputation       int       `json:"reputation"`
    Setup            int       `json:"setup"`
    Social           string    `json:"social"`
    State            string    `json:"state"`
    Status           string    `json:"status"`
    Title            string    `json:"title"`
    Website          string    `json:"website"`
}

type milestoneDTOS struct {
    Category          string    `json:"category"`
    CreatedBy         string    `json:"createdBy"`
    CreatedDate       int       `json:"createdDate"`
    Description       string    `json:"description"`
    Enabled           bool      `json:"enabled"`
    EndDate           time.Time `json:"endDate"`
    IsCurrentPosition bool      `json:"isCurrentPosition"`
    IsEnabled         bool      `json:"isEnabled"`
    LastModifiedBy    time.Time `json:"lastModifiedBy"`
    LastModifiedDate  int       `json:"lastModifiedDate"`
    ObjectID          string    `json:"objectID"`
    Organization      string    `json:"organization"`
    PictureURL        string    `json:"pictureURL"`
    Profile           string    `json:"profile"`
    Score             float64   `json:"score"`
    StartDate         time.Time `json:"startDate"`
    Tags              []string  `json:"tags"`
    Title             string    `json:"title"`
    URL               string    `json:"url"`
    UserID            string    `json:"userId"`
}

type publicDTO struct {
    Profile       profile         `json:"profile"`
    MilestoneDTOS []milestoneDTOS `json:"milestoneDTOS"`
}
```